# How to ask fopr the RecipientView

Tags: docusignapi

I want to get a specific recipient view from an enveloppe. Here is the data I have for the recipient from an API call:

```
[#<DocuSign_eSign::Signer:0x0055e9239b8388 @creation_reason="sender", @email="email@qsdqsd.com", 
@is_bulk_recipient="false", 
@name="fake name", 
@note="", 
@recipient_id="1", 
@recipient_id_guid="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX", @recipient_supplies_tabs="true", @require_id_lookup="false", @role_name="customer", 
@routing_order="1", 
@status="sent", 
@user_id="XXXXXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">]>
```

And here is my current request payload.

```
recipient_view_request={
          "user_id": user_id_from_previous_request,
          "userName": unrelated_name,
          'email': unrelated_email,
          "returnUrl": return_url,
          "authenticationMethod": "email"
        }
```

The link that is returned is for the wrong user, allowing to sign as this incorrect user. It ignore the user_id param. How do I make a request with the correct user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you setting clientuserid for the recipient, RecipientView can only be generated for embeddedrecipients. You need to set clientUserId for the recipient for whom you want to do embedded signing. You can find embedded signing examples at https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html also you can check embedded signing example at https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview, check section [2] Create Envelope with an Embedded Recipient and [3] Create Recipient View (Embedded Signing)

Comment: Is it possible to add a client_user_id to already sent envelopes ?

Comment: Yes, you need to use update Recipients call, `PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients` as documented here, [Update Recipients] (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/), but you will able to update only those recipient who have not completed signing ceremony. And another thing is embedded recipient do not receive any email notification from DocuSign to complete the signing ceremony.